# How to apply page background images in tabris, preferable using stylesheets for iOS and/or Android devices

Tags: stylesheet, tabris

this is not clear to me from the documentation and from the current behavior I see in my app: The stylesheets work nice using a web browser, but not on the mobile app.

So what I was looking for is how to apply different background images in our mobile app (or at least colors) to the navigation page (top level pages list) and any other pages. We would like to apply different styles to the our current, I guess default style but don't know how to do this. So at this point I do not know what I can ask our graphics designer to provide.

Any docs that I missed or examples I can look at?

Thanks,
Vincent

Answer (score 0):

The styles you are using for the web are applied by RAP's theming. Currently Tabris does not support theming. The only option you have at the moment is to use the SWT setBackground.Image methods on the widget itself. To behave different as in the web you could use RWT.getClient().getService( ClientDevice.class ).getPlatform(); to distinguish between the mobile and web client.